# How can I get comment creation date?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, datetime, comments

How can I get comments creation date of a node and convert it to custom format in my theme, I tried to make some operations on node comments date in "MyTheme.theme" file and in `MyTheme_preprocess_comment` section.

Comment: Is this about Drupal 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_comment
*/
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  // Getting the node creation time stamp from the comment object.
  $date = $variables['comment']->getCreatedTime();
  // Here you can use drupal's format_date() function, or some custom php date formatting.
  $variables['created'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval(REQUEST_TIME - $date);
  $variables['submitted'] = t('@username commented !datetime', array('@username' => $variables['author'], '!datetime' => '<span class="comments-ago">' . $variables['created'] . ' ago </span>'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,But,  What's usage or profit `\Drupal::service('date.formatter')` have in this Case?

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani The 'date.formatter' service is the Drupal 8 way of formatting dates, and will take into consideration timezones, localization, etc.

Comment: @Vamsi formatInterval() is discouraged, but not officially deprecated yet.  formatTimeDiffUntil(), formatTimeDiffSince, and formatDiff() are the preferred methods in the service for timeago foramts.  There is an issue about this, but I don't have it handy.